# Renaming a Debian host via script: Need my work checked

Tags: debian, hostname

Just want to make sure I've covered all the bases (not counting domain names). As far as I can tell, everything is working.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Needs 1 and only 1 argument
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 NEW-HOSTNAME" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# I could probably put in a regex here to check that the hostname is good.

# Change the hostname in the session (does this even do anything?)
sudo hostname -b ${1}

# Change the visible hostname permanently (writes to /etc/hostname)
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname ${1}

# Change the mail hostname if there is one
if [ -f "/etc/mailname" ]; then
  echo ${1} | sudo tee /etc/mailname > /dev/null
fi

# Change the hostname in the hosts file (aka the fun one)
my_temp=`mktemp`
grep -v "127.0.1.1" < /etc/hosts > ${my_temp}
echo 127.0.1.1    ${1} >> ${my_temp}
sudo cp ${my_temp} /etc/hosts
rm -f ${my_temp}

# And now for a reboot
echo "Rebooting."
sudo shutdown -r now
```

I suppose if I was really neurotic, I could save the old hostname and use it as a reference after reboot to clean out any leftover xauth cookies.

Comment: Lots of double-quoting errors and an antiquated backtick. Take a look: https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Rather than using `sudo` for every little thing why not require that the entire script runs as root?

Comment: when writing shell scripts you should almost always put `-e` in the shabang or run `set -e`.  Otherwise, the script won't actually fail when a command inside the script returns nonzero.

Comment: I think they way you're doing your `/etc/hosts` update is kinda crazy.  You've left out ipv6 versions of localhost   and an other aliases added to localhost.  Instead I recommend an inline sed to change the old hostname to the new.